# How to add zero (0) in blanks in a big file (example file is below)

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

Here is a example file where I need to replace blanks with zero

```
A   2   2   2   2   2
B   2   2   2   2   2
C   2   2   2   2   2
D   A               
E   B               
F
D
R
```

Comment: In the original example where no spaces, those were added as I formatted it. Original example had only tabs as blanks.

Comment: Please clarify the question by posting what your desired output should look like.

Answer (score 3):

The following should work:

```
tr '\t' 0 < file 1<> file
```

Comment: These commands are not working unfortunately and giving me out put file without any change. My file contain 150 rows in total with 96 rows having 4783484 columns and remaining have only 6 columns. So I need to add zero 4783478 times in these rows.

Comment: @user55103 What is the *exact* command you are executing, including the filename? Do you receive any errors?

Comment: tr ' ' 0 < ped3.ped< ped4.ped . I donot receive any error message but it returnd me ped4.ped file without any change (no zero added)

Comment: @user55103 Your syntax is wrong. Read the answer again, replace `file` with the filename.

Comment: `tr ' ' 0 < ped3.ped 1<> ped4.ped`?

Comment: Thanks for you help but  it is not working, I am afraid. May be because my file is tab delimited.

Comment: Or may be because missing at the end

Comment: @user55103 That would be the reason, then. Answer edited.

Comment: This edited answer is changing
27      00107XY 0       0       1       1
25      00105XX 0       0       1       
31      0012XY                  1       2
34      0038XX                  1       
39      00DBFXY 0       0       1       
37      0067XX  0       0       1       

To
27000107XY00000101
25000105XX0000010
3100012XY000102
3400038XX00010
39000DBFXY0000010
3700067XX0000010

Comment: I mean adding an additional zero inbetween two columns.

Comment: I used this command on an example file (awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" } { for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i ~ /^ *$/) $i = 0 }; 1' Book2.ped > Book4.ped ) and it handles missing value in the middle very well but cannot add zero at the end

Comment: I don't see how this solution should work at all. It just indiscriminately replaces tabs with zeros.

Comment: @200_success Which is... what was asked for by the OP?

Comment: I interpret the task be replacing _empty fields_ (i.e. consecutive tabs or a tab at the end of the line) with 0.

Comment: @200_success That doesn't correlate with what the OP said in this comment thread about it being tab-delimited.

Answer (score 1):

Filter it through

```
perl -pe 's/\t(?=\t|$)/\t0/g'
```

In Perl regular expressions,

- `\t` is a <kbd>Tab</kbd>
- `(?=…)` is a zero-width look-ahead assertion, which I've used to match only empty fields.

The Perl command line options

- `-e` specifies that the next command-line argument contains the Perl program
- `-p` inserts boilerplate code to make it act like `awk`: executing the Perl code for each line in the input and print the processed line.

Answer (score 0):

Filter it through

```
awk '{ while (gsub("\t\t", "\t0\t"));
       sub("\t$", "\t0");
       print }'
```

The solution is awkward because in general, neither `awk` nor `sed` supports zero-width look-ahead assertions.  Therefore, I have to look for two consecutive tabs.  As a result, I also have to handle tab at the end of the line separately.

Comment: I think you can use `"\t"` also in `gsub` and `sub`. No need for `C-v <tab>`